# Unknown function rmean()

Tags: stata

I have multiple variables that inform me about education and they are all measured the same way so I want to generate a single mean from all of them.

I used the `rmean` function but it gives me the following error:

> unknown function rmean()

The code I used can be found below:

```
generate educationlevel=rmean(gea_ea2534f gea_ea2534m gea_ea3544f)
```

Is there an alternative to `rmean()` or is there a solution to my mistake?

I have used it before and it worked without flaw.

Answer (score 0):

The function `rmean()` (now deprecated but still usable) is the same function as `rowmean()` for the `egen` command and cannot be used with the `generate` command.

Consider the following toy example based on your variable names:

```
clear
set obs 5

generate gea_ea2534f = rnormal()
generate gea_ea2534m = rnormal()
generate gea_ea3544f = rnormal()

egen educationlevel_1 = rmean(gea_ea2534f gea_ea2534m gea_ea3544f)
egen educationlevel_2 = rowmean(gea_ea2534f gea_ea2534m gea_ea3544f)

list, abbreviate(16)

     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | gea_ea2534f   gea_ea2534m   gea_ea3544f   educationlevel_1   educationlevel_2 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    .3490815     -.4092931     -.6905914          -.2502677          -.2502677 |
  2. |    1.850225     -.3951465     -1.178263           .0922718           .0922718 |
  3. |   -.4527464      .9515566     -.6192825          -.0401574          -.0401574 |
  4. |      .09648     -1.276887      .6211842          -.1864076          -.1864076 |
  5. |    .3620505       .011035      .9618655           .4449837           .4449837 |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```